# Angular login form cookies not working in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: node.js, angular, firefox, cookies, browser

The Angular(version 6.0) form is not able to recognize pre-filled values in the Mozilla Firefox browser. whereas I can access the same thing in Google Chrome.

Not able to login with prefilled username and password saved in the browser cookies, Is there is any problem in Firefox to be fixed while working with angular forms.

[In the first Image here in Firefox I tried to use username and password saved in cookies. When I clicked on the login button nothing happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGL8Z.png) 
[When I checked then console and logged the data over there it was showing email string as null and password string was correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGL8Z.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ju2X.png]
As soon as I'm clicking on the email text field browser recognizes the email and shows the correct email string on the console log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bo67.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
console.log(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
```